# declare enum for using in array?

Tags: java, arrays, enums

Sorry for probably easy question.

I need array of flags

```
boolean[20] isTownVisited
```

But it is not convient to use int in it, i want to use strings:

```
 isTownVisited[Town.Milan] = true;
```

or

```
 return isTownVisited[Town.Rome]
```

I've tried to declare enum

```
enum Town {Milan, Rome, Florence, Napoli}
```

But I still can't use it to index my boolean array. How to fix this problem, may I write something like:

```
enum Town {Milan = 0, Rome = 1, Florence = 2, Napoli = 3}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an EnumSet.

```
Set<Town> towns = EnumSet.of(Town.Milan);

towns.add(Town.Rome);

return towns.contains(Town.Napoli);
```

Under the bonnet the EnumMap and EnumSet uses `int ordinal();` The EnumSet uses a bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

Gee... I would have just use this:

```
boolean[Town.values().length] isTownVisited;

isTownVisited[Town.Milan.ordinal] = true;
```

Comment: thanks that's probably what I was looking for :) but now EnumSet looks pretty good... I've tried use it and I'm happy with it because collections more easy to use than arrays...

Answer (score 0):

u can always make a public static class with all the variables declared

so

```
public class Town{
   public static bool Rome = false;
   // and the rest
}
```

Then u can simply do Town.rome to acess the variables...

Note dont make static variables if you want to use these variables inside multiple objects.

In that case make normal variables and then create a new object and use the variables of that object

Comment: i would loose ability of iterating all towns

Comment: assign unique indexes to the towns in the static class and create an array of bools as u did originally. That way you can get both iteration as well as the ablility to use names..

Comment: e.g rome = 0; london =1 ; etc all constants

Comment: so isVisited[0] becomes isvisited[Towns.rome].. 
Hopefully this solves your problem

Comment: P.S  I believe you can cast enums to int x = (int) Town.Rome;

Comment: no I can't cast enum to int. Eclipse says me "Cannot cast Town.Rome to int"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a map instead of an array. You can create a `Map<Town, Boolean>`, where `Town` is an enum, and the boolean is whether that town has been visited or not.